# Event details saving issue in android calendar

Tags: android, events, calendar, save

I facing a events details saving in android calendar from the long time. I am able to save the details in devices below android version 2.2.3 but for above it doesn't save to calendar. Here is my code:

---

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
            Uri events = null;
            if(getCalendarUriBase(this)!=null)
            {   
            Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            // event insert

             long eventdate1=Date.parse(“23/07/2012”);
             long eventdate2=Date.parse((“23/07/2012”);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("calendar_id", 1);
            values.put("title","Event 1");
            values.put("allDay", 0);
            values.put("dtstart", eventdate1); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
            values.put("dtend", eventdate2); // ends 60 minutes from now
            values.put("description", "Description 1");
            values.put("eventLocation", "xyz");
            values.put("visibility", 0);
            values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
            try{
            try{    
            events = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return false;
            }
            // reminder insert

            Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(events.getLastPathSegment()));
            values.put( "method", 1 );
            values.put( "minutes", 10 );
            cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
```

---

```
private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {

    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }
    }
    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

### **********

Where I am missing something. Please help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think the problem is in

```
values.put("visibility", 0);
```

I think that there is no column in database with that name. It's the same with column named *transparency*. I found it in some tutorials on the net

Comment: I guess that here "visibility" refer for showing event entry in calendar (like true or false). Could you please let me know that what should be the probable solution?

Comment: Don't use _values.put("visibility", 0);_. It will work without it